# Which is the proper way to declare this kind of object for swagger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, swagger

I'm having a hard time trying to create this kind of object on `swagger.json` on the spec file

```
    parameter name: :user, in: :body, schema: {
      type: :object,
      properties: {
        username: { type: :string },
        password: { type: :string },
      },
      required: %w[username password]
    }
```

my objetive is to do this format

```
{
  user:{
     username: { type: :string },
     password: { type: :string },
  },
}
```

I've tried using other proprierties and formats such as changing the properties to include user: or the type, but none have worked so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to configure it like this.

```rb
parameter name: :user, in: :body, schema: {
  type: :object,
  properties: {
    user: {
      type: :object,
      properties: {
        username: { type: :string },
        password: { type: :string }
      },
      required: %w[username password]
    }
  },
  required: %w[user]
}
```